# How to checkpoint by minibatch in Keras

Tags: keras

I know that I can use [ModelCheckpoint in Keras](https://keras.io/callbacks/) for checkpointing a model every epoch (or every few epochs, depending on what I want).

I am getting my data for each minibatch from a fit_generator, and it takes a very long time to evaluate each minibatch. I'd like to be able to checkpoint by minibatch instead of by epoch. How can I do this in Keras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a custom callback for this. Steps are :

1. Subclass ModelCheckpoint   (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py) or create new one if you do not need filename pattern etc.
2. Add method that would be called at the end of each batch

> ```
> class BatchModelCheckpoint(keras.callbacks.Callback):
>      def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
>         self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
> ```